# WebSecurity.UserExists creates user if it doesn't exist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 code, if I call **WebSecurity.UserExists** and give it the name of a nonexistent user then it returns false (as it should), but, as a side effect, it creates the user record.  Thus, if I call it a second time with the same username it returns true (since the user now exists).

What's that all about?  Is this a known bug?

Bob

Comment: WebSecurity is used by WebMatrix. Shouldn't you be using one of the FindUser methods in System.Web.Security.Membership?

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused about what WebMatrix is and its relationship to MVC 4.  As near as I can tell (someone please correct or expand on this), the Powers That Be incorporated stuff that was originally developed for the standalone WebMatrix product into MVC 4.  In particular, the WebSecurity methods are baked into the MVC 4 Forms Authentication template code, and are the preferred "simplified" methods to use.

Comment: Just FYI, instead of calling  

  WebSecurity.UserExists(name)  

I call  
  WebSecurity.GetUserId(userName) >= 0  

(Note that GetUserId apparently returns -1 if the specified userName does not exist. This behavior is not documented on the F1 web page.)

Comment: I am checking userexists with WebSecurity.UserExists(username) and it doesnt create any user record in database.                       bool userExist = WebSecurity.UserExists(model.UserName);
            if (userExist)
            {//....}